# Is there a way to distinguish fat jar from thin jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I want to avoid having fat jars in classpath.
Is there a way to detect if a certain jar file is compiled from several jar files or not (besides looking at its size)?

Answer (score 2):

It is not directly possible. The only way would be to look, whether the dependencies of the library are included. Suppose you have a library with the class a/b/Foo and it has a dependency on the external library (with one class, too) bar.jar with class c/d/Baz.
Now, If there are both classes in the jar (a/b/Foo and c/d/Baz), I would say, that this is a fat jar.

Answer (score -1):

if you using maven plugin the one below

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
```

you can use the configuration that contain **descriptorRefs** which tell maven what type assembly this config should build.

example:

```
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
```

**jar-with-dependencies** is a pre fabricate descriptor by maven
tell maven to build jar with dependencies similar term to FatJar

then just launch **mvn clean package**.

For thin Jar i don't have solution but if you have a spring boot project
this repo can do it.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot.experimental/spring-boot-thin-layout/1.0.25.RELEASE

maybe a mix of the 2 can help you.